# AEM Rich Text Source Editor Anchor Tag Stripping href formed like Sightly tag

Tags: html, aem, xss, sightly

In my AEM project, we have client-side dynamic variable functionality which checks for any strings that are formed inside of a `${` `}` wrapper. The dynamic variable values are coming from our cookies. Replacing this with a more friendly format that does not conflict with Sightly is not an option at the moment, so please don't tell me to do that :)

When creating an anchor tag in the source editor of the Text core component, I am setting the href as the following: `href="/content/en/opt-in.html?hash=${/profile/hash}"`. The anti-Samy configuration is blocking the href attribute from being rendered on this element, but I have tried to add the following to the overlayed file `/apps/cq/xssprotection/config.xml`:

`<regexp name="expressionURLWithSpecialCharacters" value="(\$\{(\w|\/|:)+\})"/>`

```
        <regexp-list>
            <regexp name="onsiteURL"/>
            <regexp name="offsiteURL"/>
            <regexp name="expressionURL"/>
            <regexp name="expressionURLWithSpecialCharacters"/>
        </regexp-list>
```

^ inside of the `<attribute name="href">` block of common-attributes. Is there something else I need to do in order to make this not be filtered out so that it can be correctly parsed by the global variable replacement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlad, your second point was helpful in that I hadn't considered that one of the regular expressions in the XSS Protection configuration href attribute block needed to match the `${/profile/hash}` **in addition to** the rest of the URL preceding and following it. Although to your first point, the RTE actually **did** save the special characters as-is into the JCR and did not encode them, probably since I was using the source editor mode and not the inline text editor.

What I ended up doing was creating a new regular expression as follows:

```
<regexp name="onsiteURLWithVariableExpression"
        value="(?!\s*javascript(?::|&amp;colon;))(?:(?://(?:(?:(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~])|(?:%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit})|(?:[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]))*@)?(?:\[(?:(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){6}(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:\p{XDigit}{1,4})|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])))|(?:::(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){5}(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:\p{XDigit}{1,4})|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])))|(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}){0,1}::(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){4}(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:\p{XDigit}{1,4})|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])))|(?:(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){0,1}\p{XDigit}{1,4})?::(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){3}(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:\p{XDigit}{1,4})|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])))|(?:(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){0,2}\p{XDigit}{1,4})?::(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){2}(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:\p{XDigit}{1,4})|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])))|(?:(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){0,3}\p{XDigit}{1,4})?::(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){1}(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:\p{XDigit}{1,4})|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])))|(?:(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){0,4}\p{XDigit}{1,4})?::(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:\p{XDigit}{1,4})|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])))|(?:(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){0,5}\p{XDigit}{1,4})?::(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}))|(?:(?:(?:\p{XDigit}{1,4}:){0,6}\p{XDigit}{1,4})?::))]|(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])\.(?:\p{N}|[\x31-\x39]\p{N}|1\p{N}{2}|2[\x30-\x34]\p{N}|25[\x30-\x35])|(?:(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~])*|(?:%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit})*|(?:[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=])*))(?::\p{Digit}+)?(?:/|(/(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~]|%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit}|[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]|:|@)+/?)*))|(?:/(?:(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~]|%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit}|[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]|:|@)+(?:/|(/(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~]|%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit}|[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]|:|@)+/?)*))?)|(?:(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~]|%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit}|[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]|:|@)+(?:/|(/(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~]|%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit}|[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]|:|@)+)*)))?(?:\?(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|(\$\{(\w|\/|:)+\})|[\p{N}-._~]|%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit}|[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]|:|@|/|\?)*)?(?:#(?:(?:\p{L}\p{M}*)|[\p{N}-._~]|%\p{XDigit}\p{XDigit}|[!$&amp;&apos;()*+,;=]|:|@|/|\?)*)?"/>
```

which is just the `onsiteURL` with my original `expressionURLWithSpecialCharacters: (\$\{(\w|\/|:)+\})` value added as a group in the query string parameter section. This enabled AEM to accept this as an href value in my anchor tag.

I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. The RTE will encode your URL and turn `hash=${/profile/hash}` into `hash=$%7B/profile/hash%7D` when storing into JCR
2. Even if you pass 1, the expression you are trying to use will only match EXACTLY the URL of `${/profile/hash}`. You would need to expand the expression to include everything else (scheme, domain/host, path, query etc.). Think `onsiteURL` and `offsiteURL`  but allowing your expression as well in query parameters. Have a look at https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-xss/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/xss/impl/XSSFilterImpl.java#L115 to get a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding disableXSSFiltering="{Boolean}true”?